# Script to rename and reboot a Computer throws out an file access error despite being run in an admin PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-workflow

Running a workflow which renames and restarts the computer results in an error.

I had to put in screenshots because I somehow could post the code in here.

[PowerShell code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNH7S.png)

[Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7LAe.png)

Comment: Please post your code and error message as text and not screenshots.

Comment: You need to start PS by right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: @jdweng I did ran it in the Admin PowerShell

Comment: Are you admin on both local and remote machine?  Is the account the same on both local and remote?  If you are an admin on both local and remote machine credentials are not needed.  Most windows networks only allow default credentials and will fail with a username and password.  If you are on a corporate network, Group Policy is enforced.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking for?

```
$newName = "New name"
$computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME

Rename-Computer -ComputerName $computer -NewName $newName -Restart

Write-Host "Computer name changed to $newName. Rebooting now."
```

I mean, this isn't a modified version of your code but it does what it seems to be what you asked for:

> Rename and reboot the computer

Please let me know if it's what you're after.